# PHP error when trying to send email using Swift Mailer

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I ve tried everything, i don't know how to fix this, so, i am using this Swift Mailer library to send a confirmation email. So here is the code from my index.php

```
if($confirm){

            //include the swift class
            include_once 'inc/php/swift/swift_required.php';

            //put info into an array to send to the function
            $info = array(
                'username' => $username,
                'email' => $email,
                'key' => $key);

            //send the email
            if(send_email($info)){

                //email sent
                $action['result'] = 'success';
                array_push($text,'Thanks for signing up. Please check your email for confirmation!');

            }else{

                $action['result'] = 'error';
                array_push($text,'Could not send confirm email');

            }

        }
```

And my send_email function is in another php file functions.php

```
//send the welcome letter
function send_email($info){

    //format each email
    $body = format_email($info,'html');
    $body_plain_txt = format_email($info,'txt');
        //setup the mailer
    $transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance(smtp.gmail.com,465,ssl)
       ->setUsername('my email here')
          ->setPassword('my password');

    $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
    $message = Swift_Message::newInstance();
    $message ->setSubject('Welcome to Site Name');
    $message ->setFrom(array('somedomain.com' => 'somethinghere'));
    $message ->setTo(array($info['email'] => $info['username']));

    $message ->setBody($body_plain_txt);
    $message ->addPart($body, 'text/html');

    $result = $mailer->send($message);

    return $result;

}
```

The error that i am getting is

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Swift_MailTransport::setUsername() in /srv/disk7/something/www/something/signup/inc/php/functions.php on line 31

How can i fix this? I am a beginner in php.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing `Swift_MailTransport::newInstance(smtp.gmail.com,465,ssl)` fails to create the expected instance.

BTW, shouldn't it be `Swift_MailTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com',465,'ssl')` (*i.e. smtp.gmail.com and ssl in quotes*)?

Comment: No, it has to be in " "

Comment: Same thing. My question still stands.

Comment: Please mind your language! Not everyone is in the same "mood" as you!

Answer (score 0):

[`Swift_MailTransport`](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html#the-mail-transport), from the documentation...

> ...sends messages by delegating to PHP's internal mail() function.
>
> In my experience -- and others' -- the mail() function is not particularly predictable, or helpful.

Another thing it does not have is a `setUsername` or `setPassword` method.

I'd say you want to use [`Swift_SmtpTransport`](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html#the-smtp-transport)

One more thing; as pointed out by others, your string arguments should be quoted, ie

```
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 465, 'ssl');
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you haven't included the Swift Mail class.